# Selecting different parameters for a group by statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, min

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

Here in this dataset, there is No `NULL` value for all these 3 columns, also `user_name` and `recording_msid` pair can repeat but each repeated pair will have a distinct timestamp in `listened_at`.

Note for distinct pairs of `(user_name, recording_msid)` the `listened_at` can repeat.

I am trying to group by the table using:

```
SELECT
  user_name, recording_msid, COUNT(*)
FROM
  `listenbrainz.listenbrainz.listen`
GROUP BY
  user_name, recording_msid;
```

and get results like:

[image]

But what I also want in this result is another column of `listened_at` where each row has the oldest `listened_at` value for every repeating pair of `(user_name, recording_msid)` i.e. every row in the below table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what I also want in this result is another column of `listened_at` where each row has the oldest `listened_at` value for every repeating pair of (`user_name`, `recording_msid`)

Use `MIN()`:

```
SELECT
    user_name, 
    recording_msid, 
    COUNT(*) no_records, 
    MIN(listened_at) min_listened_at
FROM `listenbrainz.listenbrainz.listen`
GROUP BY user_name, recording_msid;
```

Comment: How is it `COUNT(*)` works with `MIN(listened_at)`. I assumed `*` worked for all items? Any tips for this literature.

Comment: Just like `COUNT()`, `MIN()` operates on the group of rows defined by the `GROUP BY` clause. So this gives you the minimum value of `listened_at` for the current `(user_name, recording_msid)` tuple.